# File won't compile after printing it

Tags: compilation-error, printing

Every time I print the .pdf file of a LaTeX document, it won't compile and build the tex files afterwards. It doesn't matter the size or what packages I have in my file. I end up having to copy and paste the entire document into a new file. On the most recent file I received this:

[image]

This has always happened to me over the many years of using LaTeX but I decided to finally find out why and hopefully fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Edited: Additional system information

[image]

Comment: Looks like the PDF file is locked, maybe because it has been opened by another application in the background in order to be printed. Try to close the file everywhere and then compile again.

Comment: Yes, I've closed everything that would be using the file and I still get this message. It also happens if I've uploaded a file (turning in an assignment online).

Comment: Obviously this doesn't happen to other people or you would find lots of questions about it on the net. So it is something specific to your system. So why do you leave out any specific information? You don't say which OS , which tex system and which editor you use and how you print. In case you are using windows: previews/thumbnails in the file explorer can block a pdf.

Comment: I'm sorry @UlrikeFischer, I really didn't know what information to include because it is such a strange problem and I'm clueless about it. I have Windows 11, I use MikTex and TeX studio. I print pdfs by opening Adobe Acrobat and I upload pdfs as well. I normally compile using PdfLaTeX. I've added a pic of the Commands page from TeX studio if that helps. Please let me know what other information would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What printer do you have (and has it been the same for the entire time this issue has been happening)? I remember I had a printer years ago that had drivers which would cause similar issues with certain applications.

Comment: I have a HP6962 and I've had this printer for several years. Everything including MikTex, TeX studio, and the printer have updated versions and drivers as of last week.

Comment: If you open one of the PDF files in a different program (for example a web browser), and print it from there, do you get the same problem? I wonder if maybe it's just Acrobat causing the issue.

Comment: I've never done that but I will try it tomorrow (my printer is in another room and will wake it's occupants). Why would it also happen when I just upload pdfs to my classes as well? Do you think that would also be an Acrobat issue?

Comment: @cantor'ssloth What program do you use to upload the PDFs?

Comment: We use Canvas for all school assignments.

Comment: Canvas as-in [this Canvas?](https://www.instructure.com/) I recall that has some integration with Adobe Creative Cloud (and so I suspect you're using Acrobat via CC too) in which case I'm practically certain it's the Adobe Collaboration Synchronizer refusing to unlock files properly after Acrobat has closed. I've seen this before. I'll write up a proper answer soon.